# Login in to website using python requests : 400 - Bad Request

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

I am trying to login to a website using requests.

The login process is in two stages:

- Step one: enter email on the first page. 1st page source code below:

  ```
   <div id="content" class="js-container" data-component="two-step-login-form"> 
    <div class="lgn-box">
     <form name="enter-email-form" action="/login/submitEmail" class="js-email-lookup-form" method="POST" data-test-id="enter-email-form" novalidate="true">
      <input name="location" value="https://www.mywebsite.com/" type="hidden">
      <input name="continueUrl" value="" type="hidden">
      <input name="readerId" value="" type="hidden">
      <input name="loginUrl" value="/login?location=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com%2F" type="hidden">
      <div class="lgn-box__title">
          <h1 class="lgn-heading--alpha">Sign in</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="o-forms-group">
          <label for="email" class="o-forms-label">Email address</label>
          <input id="email" class="o-forms-text js-email" name="email" maxlength="64" autocomplete="off" autofocus="" required="" type="email">
          <input id="password" name="password" style="display:none" type="password">
          <label for="password">
      </label></div>
      <div class="o-forms-group">
          <button class="o-buttons o-buttons--standout o-buttons--big" type="submit" name="Next">Next</button>
      </div>
  </form>
  ```
- Step two: enter password in the returned second page. 2nd page source code below:

  ```
   <div id="content" class="js-container" data-component="two-step-login-form"> 
    <div class="lgn-box">
     <form name="enter-password-form" action="/login?location=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com%2F" method="POST" data-test-id="enter-password-form" novalidate="">
      <input name="location" value="https://www.mywebsite.com/" type="hidden">
      <input name="continueUrl" value="" type="hidden">
      <input name="readerId" value="" type="hidden">
      <div class="lgn-box__title">
          <h1 class="lgn-heading--alpha">Sign in</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="o-forms-group">
          <a href="/login?location=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com%2F" class="js-change-email lgn-typography-bold lgn-typography-big lgn-typography-link--back">Back</a>
      </div>
      <div class="o-forms-group">
          <label for="email" class="o-forms-label">Email</label>
          <input readonly="" class="js-email o-forms-text o-forms-unskin lgn-typography-bold lgn-typography-big lgn-typography-truncate" id="email" value="" name="email" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="o-forms-group">
          <label for="password" class="o-forms-label">Password</label>
          <input id="password" name="password" class="o-forms-text" maxlength="50" autofocus="" required="" type="password">
          <small class="o-forms-additional-info"><a href="/reset-password">Forgot your password?</a></small>
      </div>
      <div class="o-forms-group lgn-utils-pack">
          <button class="o-buttons o-buttons--standout o-buttons--big" type="submit" name="Sign in">Sign in</button>
          <div class="lgn-typography-align-right">
              <input class="o-forms-checkbox" name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" value="true" checked="" type="checkbox">
              <label for="rememberMe" class="o-forms-label lgn-utils-remove-margin">Remain signed in</label>
          </div>
      </div>
  </form>
  ```

To do so, I am using the following code:

```
import requests, lxml.html

with requests.Session() as s:
    login = s.get('https://mywebsite/login')
    login_html = lxml.html.fromstring(login.text)
    hidden_inputs = login_html.xpath(r'//form//input[@type="email"]')
    form = {x.attrib["name"]: x.attrib["value"] for x in hidden_inputs}
    form['email'] = 'myemail@a.com'
    response = s.post('https://mywebsite/login', data=form)
     >> Bad Request 400 ERROR
    login_html = lxml.html.fromstring(response.text)
    hidden_inputs = login_html.xpath(r'//form//input[@type="password"]')
    form = {x.attrib["name"]: x.attrib["value"] for x in hidden_inputs}
    form['password'] = '*****'
    response = s.post('https://website/login', data=form)
     >> Bad Request 400 ERROR
    print(form)
```

Any idea how to handle that?

Thanks

(Python 3.5)

Comment: Did you tried to use mechanize?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really the right approach. What you want to do is log in while you've got DevTools or FireBug open and look at the headers to see what's required to POST the credentials, then put those into a dictionary and submit the request. For example, here's the DevTools output from this page I'm on right now:

```
General
Request URL:http://stackoverflow.com/posts/validate-body
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:151.101.129.69:80

Response Headers
view source
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:private
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:54
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Wed, 05 Apr 2017 17:53:29 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Vary:Fastly-SSL
Via:1.1 varnish
X-Cache:MISS
X-Cache-Hits:0
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control:off
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Guid:598a7e9d-7775-4ab9-9a8d-3c25d6e1984e
X-Served-By:cache-sjc3629-SJC
X-Timer:S1491414810.679660,VS0,VE141

Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:100
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:prov=40a191ef-3cbb-7b00-af35-93d7cc8df595; __qca=P0-1351948118-1491163901240; _ga=GA1.2.2042334979.1491163901; acct=t=5U3Vk9gxgP4JVyr3WBuiQjdq6athwXsO&s=dQh5bzT%2foR1RhIOInkGQZDxQ9XdG7gUv
DNT:1
Host:stackoverflow.com
Origin:http://stackoverflow.com
Referer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231181/login-in-to-website-using-python-requests-400-bad-request
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
body:This isn't really the right approach. What you want to do is inspect 
oldBody:
isQuestion:false
```

You're mainly after the `Request URL` and the `Form Data` sections.
So in this case you'd want to do something like:

```
s = requests.Session()
payload = {'body': 'The answer I\'m posting to your question', 'oldBody': '', 'isQuestion': 'false'}
response = s.post('http://stackoverflow.com/posts/validate-body', data=payload)
print(response.content)
```

Comment: The problem was that there was actually some javascript code that had to run at every turn on the page, preventing me from getting any response. I tried using Qt4python and finished by using a browser emulator like Selenium. thanks @AutomaticStatic though.